# Signals returnPressed() and editingFinished() does not work for QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I am using `editingFinished()` signals of `QLineEdit` to perform an Operation. The documentation says that this signal will be emitted when return or enter key is pressed or when it will lose focus.

It works well with the `enter key` on the numlock (`Windows` keyboard), and also when it loses focus, but when i press "return key" on the keyboard, the signal is not emitted. i tried to use the `returnPressed()` signal, it behaves the same way.

Am i missing something ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Subclass `QLineEdit`

Reimplement `keyPressEvent()`

Catch `Qt::Key_Enter` pressing and do your job or emit signal yourself

From documentation:

```
Qt::Key_Return  0x01000004   
Qt::Key_Enter   0x01000005  Typically located on the keypad.
```

Something like this:

```
void LineEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Enter)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

If you do not want subclass, you can `installEventFilter` to your dialog window, catch your lineEdit and check is `Qt::Key_Enter` was pressed.

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
        if (obj == ui->lineEdit && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
            QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
            if(Qt::Key_Enter == keyEvent->key() )
            {
                qDebug() << "numpad Enter pressed";
            }
        }
}
```

Don't forget

```
protected:
bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);//in header
```

and

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);//in constructor
```

For example:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_returnPressed()
{
    qDebug() << "numpad Enter pressed";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But i was just wondering, Though documentation says that, this signal will be emitted for both return and enter keys, then why does it works only for the enter key.

Comment: @user1703942 On my computer it works properly, catch both, so show your code or use my solution

Comment: There is not actually a code to show for that. because i am using Qt creator, and I right-clicked on QLineEdit, Selected "go to slot", and then selected the signal. and slot was created automatically. But i think if i cannot undertstand why is that, then i have no otehr option than to use your solution.

Comment: I tried using event filter. the problem is same, it works for enter key but not for return key

Comment: @user1703942 something strange, are you sure that your NumLock enabled and works properly(sorry about this stupid question). If you numLock works properly and enable, then try to catch EnterKey in clear project, maybe something blocks this key in your current project.

Comment: I am sorry, may be i did not state clearly. it works using 'enter' key on numpad but not using 'return' key.

Comment: @user1703942 then try in event filter `Qt::Key_Return` instead of `Qt::Key_Enter` How it works?

Comment: The problem was that, in my mainwindow, I was handling the return event, thats why the event filter was not catching the return event on  mainWindow

Comment: Yes my problem is solved. i stopped handling 'return' event in the mainwindow. then it started to work perfectly :)